# CSRF token missing or incorrect in angular 2 + DJango 1.10.6

Tags: django, angular

I am using Angular 2 and Django 1.10.6. I create a post method. after send request from front-end, showing CSRF token missing or incorrect.

```
user.html
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="createUser(f.value, f.valid,f)" novalidate>
....
</form>
```

Angular2 components

```
createUser(model: User, isValid: boolean, f: any) {
    // check if model is valid
    // if valid, call API to save customer
    if (isValid) {
        this.userCreateService.createUser(model).subscribe(
            res => {
                this.success = "User Create Success";
                this.user = new User();
                this.errorMsg=null
            },
            err => {
                this.errorMsg = err;
                this.success=null;
            });

    }
}
```

This is my Angular2 service

```
      @Injectable()
export class UserCreateService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  // private instance variable to hold base url
  private userCreateUrl = '/api/user/users/';

  // Add a new User
  createUser(body: Object): Observable<User> {
    let bodyString = JSON.stringify(body); // Stringify payload
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); // ... Set content type to JSON
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); // Create a request option

    return this.http.post(this.userCreateUrl, body, options) // ...using post request
      .map(this.extractData) // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
      .catch(this.handleError); //...errors if any
  }
```

Comment: please also provide django's views.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few moment of asking question,I have resolved my issue this way.
 created method in angular 2 service.

```
  getCookie(name) {
    let value = "; " + document.cookie;
    let parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
    if (parts.length == 2)
      return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
  }
```

And replace

```
let headers = new Headers({ 
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'}); // .Set content type to JSON
```

to

```
let headers = new Headers({ 
      'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
      'X-CSRFToken': this.getCookie('csrftoken')
     }); // ... Set content type to JSON
```

in createUser() angular service method.